# C# - How can I receive filename and file from my Java app

Tags: c#

I am very new to Java and C#. I have a java app that is sending the filename and file to a C# client using TCP Socket. I receive the data but it is corrupt when writing. I do not know how to first read the file name and then rest of the data to write the file.

I have written code that if I just send the file from my java app I successfully receive it on my C# app and write it successfully. This works 100%. Now I want to send the name and file.

Java code sending the data:

```
try {
            System.out.println("Connecting...");

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), backup_folder);
            File[] Files = file.listFiles();

            OutputStream os = m_socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

            dos.writeInt(Files.length);

            for (int count = 0; count < Files.length; count++) {
                dos.writeUTF(Files[count].getName());

            }

            for (int count = 0; count < Files.length; count++) {

                int filesize = (int) Files[count].length();
                dos.writeInt(filesize);
            }

            for (int count = 0; count < Files.length; count++) {

                int filesize = (int) Files[count].length();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[filesize];

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Files[count].toString());
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                //Sending file name and file size to the server
                bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); //This line is important
                dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                dos.flush();

                //close socket connection
                //socket.close();
            }
            m_socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error::" + e);
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.i("******* :( ", "UnknownHostException");
        }
    }
```

C# code (this is where I am having my problem)

```
private void WaitConnection()
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel2.Visible = true;
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Visible = false;

            while (true){
                m_listener.Start();
                m_client = m_listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                if (m_client.Connected == true)
                {
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        this.toolStripStatusLabel4.Visible = false;
                        this.toolStripStatusLabel5.Visible = false;
                        this.toolStripStatusLabel3.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                using (var stream = m_client.GetStream())
                using (var output = File.Create("C:\\Stocktake\\EDADatabase.db"))
                {
                    byte[] buffer;
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressBar1.Maximum = 50; })); //Set Progessbar maximum
                    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                        string rec = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        progressBar1.Invoke(new updatebar(this.UpdateProgress));
                    }
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        Completed = true;
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            this.m_client.GetStream().Close();
                            this.m_client.Dispose();
                            this.m_listener.Stop();
                            this.toolStripStatusLabel3.Visible = false;
                            this.toolStripStatusLabel5.Visible = true;

                        });
                        progressBar1.Invoke(new updatebar(this.UpdateProgress));
                        //break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

All I want to do is read the file name and use the file name to read and save the data to my pc.

Comment: It's kind of hard to see what's going wrong without an example of what bytes the Java app is sending and the C# service is receiving. Maybe it has to do with the [`writeUTF` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-) writing in a "modified" UTF-8 format.

Comment: From the research I have done I am understanding that the way I am handling the receiving of the file in my C# app is incorrect. Currently it seems that I am reading the filename being sent as part of the file size (filedata)  and that is why my file that is being saved is corrupted. I need to handle it separately and that is what I am battling with. The var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer,0,bytesRead); part of my code I am pure just seeing if I do get the filename.